# Wordpress loading delay

Tags: wordpress, performance, google-chrome-devtools

This problem occurred several days ago. Basically the site loads fine the first few seconds. Then it freezes for 5-6 seconds and then it loads the rest. When using the network tab in Google Devtools there is only white space in the waterfall these 5-6 seconds (see my screenshot) and then it loads the rest of the site.

[image]

What else should I look for to uncover the cause?
The url to my site is https://hafsten.se

Comment: Could you provide us with a URL so people can try to investigate whats going on?

Comment: It seems to work fine in my browser. Maybe it is not related to your server/site but to your browser/computer/network.

Comment: Your site needs some optimizations: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fhafsten.se%2F. Follow these suggestions and your page load times should get better.

Comment: As @cabrerahector mentioned, your site could stand some optimizing. Things you'll want to consider include caching, minification, using a CDN, and image compression.  Another good site for seeing what's going on with your page load times is gtmetrix.com